# In Apache POI HSSF, Cell Type Still Shows Up as "General" Excel, Even Though it's Number-Formatted

Tags: apache, coding-style, format, apache-poi, hssf

I am using Apache POI HSSF to generate an Excel spreadsheet from my Java Web app.

I need a cell formatted as **"Number"** with 2 decimal points. (My values in Java are BigDecimals, but I can convert them to doubles, no problem.) I am using this code:

```
CellStyle numericStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
numericStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0.00"));

// output in this new style...
row.createCell(cellnum).setCellValue(((BigDecimal)value).doubleValue());
row.getCell(cellnum).setCellStyle(numericStyle);
```

The issue is that, even though this works, Excel still shows my cells as **General**. They need to be shown as **Number**. As a result, for example, 0 is shown as 0, but it should be 0.00, which would happen if the format was correct (**Number**).

I see that it gets generated as **General** because I can right-click on a cell and then choose "Format Cells" to see what it is right now. It needs to be set to "Number" by Apache POI HSSF.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct format string for the built in format?

Comment: It is correct according to this listing:
http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html
But if you have any other format strings in mind, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the [Apache POI API](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29) it looks like you should be able to specify the cell's type.

```
...
Cell cell = row.createCell(...);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you haven't yet found an answer for your question.

One way to display numbers with two decimals is to set a cell style. This allows you to customize the number of decimal places and the decimal separator, among other things.

```
protected CellStyle getCellStyle(HSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(
        workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("#,##0.00"));
        return cellStyle;
}
```

Later on, when you fill your workbook, you apply this cellStyle to the desired cells:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = getCellStyle();
//...
// create your cell
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
// set the value
```

It won't show as numeric type in Excel. It shows as Custom type. But visually it should be the same, or at least close enough.